# Generate diagram from node project

Tags: node.js, webstorm

I've got the latest version of Webstorm, 10.
I'm wondering if there is a way to generate a diagram from my project with Webstorm or other tools

Comment: You may want to be more specific than "some diagram" if you want to ensure an accurate answer.

Comment: @Petrichor - some dependency  diagram/activity/class ... diagrams,anything that I can generate from my project is a good start

Comment: What kind of project? Your question is truly not easy to answer. In genereal, Webstorm can provide you some nice bindings to other software, but does not provide such functions iirc. In most cases, people want some diagram to visualise something specific or make something more transparent. Eg to get informations about complexity and coverage, you can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/plato for example; for (nearly) all in one it's sonarcube.

Comment: @mrcrgl - im talking about node project

Comment: obviously... would you please specify the need of your desire of diagrams?

Comment: http://www.agilemodeling.com/artifacts/sequenceDiagram.htm i also found out some plugin called SequenceDiagram for intellij but i couldn't understand how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you'd like to draw a dependency diagram, Webstorm is bundled with spy-js and it's great!

Here's a gif: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/download/attachments/57292834/diagrams.gif

Check out: http://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2015/02/webstorm-10-eap-140-2424/